# ffmpeg: recommended bitrate vs resolution

Tags: ffmpeg

I have high resolution video

```
  Duration: 00:06:28.80, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 15968 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 15809 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25k tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-10-11 05:35:02
      handler_name    : Alias Data Handler
      encoder         : AVC Coding
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, mono, fltp, 157 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-10-11 05:35:02
      handler_name    : Alias Data Handler
```

Its 6+min video.

I am ok with resolution of 240p (because i want to send it on whatsapp)

In order my video to look good quality what is the recommended bitrate for 240p. Also is what is the minimum bitrate below which the chances of pixelating will be there in the video.

I dont want to go for high bitrate also. Because ultimately i want the size to be not more than 240p.

I use mpv to see the video. I scale the original video to 240p, the quality after conversion should match the quality visible in mpv. That will give me first hand idea of how good is the conversion.

I expect a good amount of reduction in size(MB : where original is 740mb) of the file when reduced from 1920x1080 to 240p

I have found some information regarding this.

[image]

How much is this true

Comment: This question is asking wrt to the resolution 240p, 360p etc.

Comment: The answer remains the same.

Comment: see the edited question. I have found some info on a website.It suggests some resolution vs bitrate values. Ofcourse he is mentioning for some of his live streaming cameras. But is it closer that quality is approximately good with the values

Comment: Also i prefer to use two pass so that i can get the required bitrate. in crf we have to wait to see what will be the final bitrate. Or is there a way to check with crf, to the know the bitrate

Comment: Why is choosing a specific bitrate so important? The bitrate to achieve an acceptable quality will vary depending on the complexity of your input, the encoder you want to use, and your subjective definition of an acceptable quality level.

Comment: Ok. Then will not worry about bitrate. I am trying the following as per the solution suggested.
`ffmpeg -ss 30 -i input -t 60 -codec:v libx264 -preset medium -crf 24 -vf scale=-2:240 -codec:a copy outputmp4` . So this will first reduce the resolution to 240 and then encode using crf 24 or both act simultaneously or scaling does not matter at.

Comment: It does not matter if scale is before or after crf. Because you are encoding, and not just re-muxing, the input will be completely decoded to raw video regardless if you're filtering or not: see [flowchart](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Detailed-description).